# Нейронные сети Matlab

Tags: matlab, нейронные-сети

Всем привет) помогите пожалуйста разобраться с НС в Matlab. Есть вход из 66 нейронов, и выход с одним нейроном.таких примеров 600. обучается все нормально.

```
net=newff([-1 1],[5 1],{'tansig' 'purelin'});
net.trainParam.epochs=1000;
net.inputs{1}.size=66;
net=train(net,input,output);
```

Хочу узнать ответ на тестовых данных, пишу в командную строку net({вектор из 66 чисел}), выводит 66 значений, а не одно, как должно быть на выходе. Что делать? как узнавать ответ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Моделирование сети (использование сети для решения поставленной задачи).

Для того, чтобы применить обученную сеть для обработки данных, необходимо воспользоваться функцией `sim` :

```
Y=sim(net,p);
```

где `p` – набор входных векторов, `Y` – результат анализа в виде набора выходных векторов.